# Recovering DATA from HDD pulled from failed NAS

Tags: linux, data-recovery, nas

I pulled out a HDD from the My Book Live (Western Digital) NAS because it doesn't connect anymore.

Product info: http://www.wdc.com/en/products/products.aspx?id=280

I am trying to recover data from the drive. Windows can't read the filesystem but I could see 4 partitions, so I booted into Ubuntu live.

The drive shows up on Linux but prompts this error and is not accessible:

*Error mounting: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdi4,
missing codepage or helper program, or other error
In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
dmesg | tail or so*

I am a Linux noob so I need some help here.

With further research on Google, I am running TestDisk to analyse the drive.
I don't know what partition type it is so I picked EFI GPT:
Code :

```
[Intel  ] Intel/PC partition
>[EFI GPT] EFI GPT partition map (Mac i386, some x86_64...)
[Humax  ] Humax partition table
[Mac    ] Apple partition map
[None  ] Non partitioned media
[Sun    ] Sun Solaris partition
[XBox  ] XBox partition
```

Right now I am running "Analyse cylinder" on it using TestDisk and it's working through the 2TB drive slowly.

[image]
How should I go about accessing the data on the disk?

Comment: What RAID setting did it have before you pulled it out? Is it just one physical drive? These are important questions that need answering before we can assist further.

Comment: Related: [Recovering the data from a failed WD My Book NAS drive](http://superuser.com/questions/33732/recovering-the-data-from-a-failed-wd-my-book-nas-drive), [recovering data from damaged Linux partition](http://superuser.com/questions/13780/recovering-data-from-damaged-linux-partition), [Is there a chkdsk equivalent available for Ubuntu?](http://superuser.com/questions/15916/is-there-a-chkdsk-equivalent-available-for-ubuntu), [Recovering data from a corrupted disk](http://superuser.com/questions/342295/recovering-data-from-a-corrupted-disk)

Comment: It's one physical drive and I don't know what RAID setting it had because everything came pre-installed. Here's the product page: http://www.wdc.com/en/products/products.aspx?id=280

Comment: @komirad its more likely a Intel/PC partition (which probably means MBR) rather than and EFI partition, which is relatively rare.

Comment: @shf301 Will give it a shot. Been a few hours and the Analyse cylinder is still running. Posted on the official forums as well: http://community.wdc.com/t5/My-Book-Live/Accessing-My-Book-Live-HDD-via-usb-enclosure-from-linux/m-p/304334/highlight/false#M6578

Comment: @shf301 ext4 is GPT?

Comment: @komirad no ext4 is a file system and GPT is a partition type - they are different things.  A partition contains a file system.  So you could have an ext4 file system on a GPT or an MBR partition.

Answer (score 2):

Got to access the data by mounting on to windows using [Ext2FSD 0.48](http://www.ext2fsd.com) patched with [Ext2fsd-0.48-bb8](http://www.acc.umu.se/~bosse/)

Step by Step from Windows 7 ([Source](http://driesve.tumblr.com/post/1560794187/how-to-mount-an-ext4-drive-in-windows-7)):

1. Download Ext2Fsd 0.48 ([ext2Fsd.com](http://driesve.tumblr.com/post/1560794187/how-to-mount-an-ext4-drive-in-windows-7)).
2. Before you installed it, you need to change the compatibility. Right click and choose Properties and set compatibility mode to Vista Service Pack 2 and run as administrator. Now you can install the Ext2Fsd-driver.
3. Ext2Fsd only supports ext2 and ext3 formatted volumes. To make Ext2Fsd can read ext4-volumes, we should patch it. Download the patch from http://www.acc.umu.se/~bosse/ (Ext2fsd-0.48-bb8)
4. Unzip the downloaded file. Open the folder fre and choose your architecture. (i386, ia64 or amd64)
5. Copy ext2fsd.sys to Windows\System32\drivers. (Keep the original file as back-up)
6. Restart your PC
7. Now you can mount your ext4-drive, by opening Ext2Mgr and select your ext4-volume, which you want to mount. Choose a mount point!

Comment: Could you perhaps edit your post to include the step by step details? At Super User, we generally prefer you include as much information as possible and not just post links.

Comment: @SimonSheehan Done :)